# fetch data in fragment from web but shown android.os.NetworkOnMainException

Tags: android, android-fragments

I tried to get data from the website in the Fragment but doesn't work the error is 
 android.os.NetworkOnMainException

The process error during the fetchData();

**Tab2Fragment.java**

```
public class Tab2Fragment extends Fragment {

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (container == null) {

            return null;
        }
        Log.i("Tab2","Creating Tab 2" );

        LinearLayout li = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_frag2_layout, container, false);
        try {
            fetchData();
        } catch (IOException e) {

        }
        return li;


    }



    public void fetchData() throws IOException{
            Log.i("Fetching!","JSOUP");
            try{
                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                String URL = "http://";
                HttpGet request = new HttpGet(URL);
                HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

                String html = "";
                InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
                StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    str.append(line);
                }
                in.close();
                html = str.toString();
                setTexts(html);

            }
            catch(Exception e){
                Log.i("Error!","JSOUP");
            }


        }
```

What should I do to fetch website data into fragmented tabs.

Comment: Google for `NetworkOnMainException`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says everything here; you cannot run any network operation on the main thread. One approach to resolve this would be putting your network code inside the `AsyncTask` class http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html